# How to read from application.yml file in Java

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, yaml

I wrote an e mail program. But I had to change the some configs, so in my project I need to know how to read from yaml for  my loginUrl

my code below;

```
  userNotificationEmail.setIsActive("F");
  userNotificationEmailRepository.save(userNotificationEmail);
  activationResultType.setResultCode(ActivationResultCode.SUCCESSFUL);
  activationResultType.setUser(userMapper.fromUser(userEntity));
  activationResultType.setLoginUrl(loginUrl);
  return activationResultType;
```

Comment: You don't. Just inject it with `@Value("name-of-property")` in your class.

Comment: Would you kindly write a simple example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your key is `loginUrl` (inside your yaml file), you can inject its value with the `@Value` annotation, inside a Spring component.

```
@Value("${loginUrl}")
private String loginUrl;
```

If it's a second level property, the path is `@Value("${yourFirstKey.loginUrl}")`.

More [documentation about reading YAML files with Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml).

Answer (score 1):

you can use @Value like below in your class to inject the value.

```
@Value("${property.name}") 
String propertyValue;
```

Still you aren't able to access value... consider below cases as well.

YML file:

```
authorization:
  server:
    baseUri: 'http://localhost:9090/'
```

use `@Value("${authorization.server.base-uri}")` instead of `@Value("${authorization.server.baseUri}")` to get YML value inside controller.

Key point to note here as per spring documentation

> If you do want to use @Value, we recommend that you refer to property names using their canonical form (kebab-case using only lowercase letters). This will allow Spring Boot to use the same logic as it does when relaxed binding @ConfigurationProperties. For example, @Value("{demo.item-price}") will pick up demo.item-price and demo.itemPrice forms from the application.properties file, as well as DEMO_ITEMPRICE from the system environment. If you used @Value("{demo.itemPrice}") instead, demo.item-price and DEMO_ITEMPRICE would not be considered.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject in your class with:

```
@Value("${propertie.name}") 
String value;
```